# Running `SELECT current_timestamp` in Dbeaver running PostgreSQL Version 12.2 gives me a date in the past

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Running `SELECT current_timestamp` in Dbeaver running PostgreSQL Version 12.2 gives me a datetime result that is 8 Days, 2 Hours and 4 minutes in the past compared to my system time. I am not sure if I need to tweak a time setting somewhere...

Comment: What happens if you run `commit;` then select `current_timestamp` again?

Comment: SELECT current_timestamp return the current timestamp of the server running postgres. are you sure that the postgresql server is in time ?

Comment: Thanks , however, running `commit` did not correct the time delay.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am trying to figure out is the server is using correct time. I am not sure where and how I should change that.

Comment: Is Postgres running on the same computer where you run Dbeaver e.g. your laptop? Did you maybe put the computer into hibernate mode? Maybe the Postgres service didn't catch up with the time then. Is the time correct when you restart Postgres?

Comment: I checked all those off and restarting the Postgres service did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two explanations I can think of:

1. the system time on the database server is off
2. the `timezone` parameter is set to a weird value in your client session

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, but its actually set to AutoCommit , and both `current_timestamp` and `clock_timestamp()` return the same thing... **`clock_timestamp` `current_timestamp`**
`2021-04-05 07:15:24` `2021-04-05 07:15:24`

Comment: Then my explanation is bogus. Sorry for jumping to conclusions. Either the system time or the `timezone` must be off.

Comment: Thanks, system time is correct but timezone is not the same as current location but I doubt that would affect things. I wonder if DBeaver uses a source other than the system time.

Comment: Restarting the Postgres service did the trick,Thanks!